# Wait for iFrame to load and use certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, settimeout, onload-event

I have an CROSS DOMAIN iframe and I need to show an alert message if the contents are not loaded.

```
var noContent = true;

 $("#iframe1").load(function () {
          noContent = false;               
        });

if(noContent)
//do my logic
```

Now my if part executes before iframe is loaded, and I am not able to verify if there is content or not.

any suggestions  ??

Comment: Yeah. Don't try it :) It is not possible to detect when the content of the iframe is loaded.

Comment: But isn't there some way out using settimeout that might help ??

Answer (score 0):

you need to move the if inside the callback:

```
var noContent = true;

 $("#iframe1").load(function () {
   //check if the contents are OK here  
   if(noContent) ...
 });
```

Comment: Since its cross domain, I cant access the contents like that. :(

Comment: oh, then js communication is going to be impossible. You may want to check this on how to overcome it: http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/